# failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed:unable to start container process: exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to run on container "server" tcp_server.py and on "client" tcp_handshake.py.
docker build seems to work, but when "docker compose up" the error appears.

this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM snisioi/retele:2021

LABEL org.opencontainers.image.authors="Sergiu Nisioi <sergiu.nisioi@fmi.unibuc.ro>"

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iptables iproute2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libnetfilter-queue-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iperf3 moreutils 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python

COPY src/*.sh /
COPY src/examples/tcp_server.py /

CMD ["python", "tcp_server.py"]
```

I tried python, also python3.

Here are the containers:

```
server:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile-chap3
        volumes:
          - ../capitolul3:/app/src
        command: python /app/src/examples/tcp_server.py 0.0.0.0


client:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile-chap3
        volumes:
            - ../capitolul3:/app/src
        tty: true
        cap_add:
          - NET_ADMIN
          - NET_RAW
          - SYS_ADMIN
        networks:
            subnet1:
              ipv4_address: 172.10.0.2
        depends_on:
            - "router"
            - "server"
        sysctls:
          - net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=reno
        command: python /app/src/examples/tcp_handshake.py server 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: What goes wrong?  Which container has the problem?  You seem to be using a custom base image; is there anything in it?

Comment: (You don't seem to be using anything at all out of your image except the Python interpreter.  I might remove the unnecessary `apt-get install` lines – with an isolated network environment and limited capabilities, a container can't usually run network-management tools – and `COPY` your source code into your image in the correct directory rather than depending on Compose `volumes:` to inject it.)